# Mocking a decorator in one Django app

Tags: python, django, mocking, django-unittest, python-mock

I want to test

- if a views decorator works properly
- if a proper view is called

So, here's decorator `get_object` and view `features` are in `myapp.views`.

```
@get_object
def features(request, object):
    return {}
```

I try mocking this:

```
new_view = Mock(__name__='features', return_value={})
decorated = get_object(new_view)

with patch('myapp.views.features') as features:
    features = decorated
    client = Client()
    response = client.get('/features')
    print new_view.call_args
```

This shows nothing, as if the mock object was not called, although I suppose it should have been.

How can I mock the decorated view properly?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `patch` you are replacing your view with a brand new `MagicMock`. Since you are manually constructing a mock for you view you should do something more like (untested):

```
new_view = Mock(__name__='features', return_value={})
features = get_object(new_view)

with patch('myapp.views.features', features):
    client = Client()
    response = client.get('/features')
    print new_view.call_args
```

This will replace `myapp.views.features` with your hand rolled mock.

In general though I would recommend that you test your decorator in isolation without using the Django test client. Your really mixing two tests into one here. The first is making sure the decorator does it's duty and the other is making sure the request is properly routed.